# Pandas sorting MultiIndex after concatenate

Tags: python, pandas

When I create a multi-indexed table in one shot, sortlevel() works as expected. However, if I concatenate multiple tables to create the same multi-indexed table, I cannot sortlevel() anymore. Full example below:

```
import pandas as pd
a=pd.DataFrame({'country':'Zimbabwe','name':'Fred'}, index=[1])
b=pd.DataFrame({'country':'Albania','name':'Jeff'}, index=[0])
not_working = pd.concat([a,b],keys=['second','first'])
working = pd.DataFrame({'country':['Zimbabwe','Albania'],'name':['Fred','Jeff']}, index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('second',1),('first',0)]))

not_working_sorted = not_working.sortlevel(0)
working_sorted = working.sortlevel(0)
```

I expect both of these to produce:

```
           country  name
first  0   Albania  Jeff
second 1  Zimbabwe  Fred
```

However, I only get that for "working". Anyone knows what I am doing wrong ? Using pandas 0.19.2

Comment: Edit: I think I see a hint. Looking at the index of working and not_working, I see this: working.index = MultiIndex(levels=[[u'first', u'second'], [0, 1]],labels=[[1, 0], [1, 0]]). But not_working.index = MultiIndex(levels=[[u'second', u'first'], [0, 1]], labels=[[0, 1], [1, 0]])

Comment: Looks like the sorting index works not to the alphabetical order of the label of the index but just to the order in which they appear in the index. Is there anyway I can change this ?

Answer (score 4):

Try this ?

```
working.sort_index()
Out[702]: 
           country  name
first  0   Albania  Jeff
second 1  Zimbabwe  Fred
```

or to be more specific

```
working.sort_index(level=[0, 1], ascending=[True, False])
```

EDIT: Your multiple index labels show as below.

```
not_working.index
Out[565]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[['second', 'first'], [0, 1]],
           labels=[[0, 1], [1, 0]])
working.index
Out[566]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[['first', 'second'], [0, 1]],
           labels=[[1, 0], [1, 0]])
```

So if you want the `not_working` sort work :

```
not_working.sort_index(level=[0, 1], ascending=[False, False])
Out[567]: 
           country  name
first  0   Albania  Jeff
second 1  Zimbabwe  Fred
```

Comment: Oh I saw this now

Comment: sort_index does not resolve my problem. You tried it on "working", but when trying it on "not_working", it does not give the same result.

Comment: @user3076411 can you try `not_working.sort_index(level=[0, 1], ascending=[False, False])`

Comment: @user3076411 Updated :)

Comment: Still hit the same issue. I think the level 0 index is just sorted at the order it was entered.

Answer (score 3):

sortlevel() is deprecated so try to use sort_index()

```
not_working.sort_index(level = 1)
```

And

```
working.sort_index(level = 1)
```

You get

```
            country     name
first   0   Albania     Jeff
second  1   Zimbabwe    Fred
```

Comment: I even do not know this function `sortlevel` :), thank you for clarify:)

Comment: Didn't notice that `sortlevel()` is already deprecated, thanks and ++ ;-)

Comment: @MaxU, just what one needs on a boring Monday afternoon :D

Comment: @Vaishali, ha-ha :-D

Comment: okay I get that this will work on level=1 because it is sorting based on the index 0 and 1. But I think this should also work when using level=0, since it should put label "first" before "second". But that does not work. That is my problem. I would like to sort the rows by outermost index alphabetically